# How to set value edittext from barcode scanner result

Tags: java, android

i want to send my value barcodescanner to myedittext

this code for scanner result

```
class ZXingScannerResultHandler implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result){
        String resultCode = result.getText();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buat_biodata);
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }
}
```

and this for edittext

```
ton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.execSQL("insert into biodata(no, nama, tgl, jk, alamat) values('" +
                    text1.setText(resultCode) + "','" +
                    text2.getText().toString() + "','" +
                    text3.getText().toString() + "','" +
                    text4.getText().toString() + "','" +
                    text5.getText().toString() + "')");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: resultCode has the value of what you want to show?

Comment: i want to send the value to text1.setText(resultCode)

Comment: Why don't you just do after String resultcode = result.getText(); text1.settext(resultcode);

Answer (score 1):

After getting the result code to:

```
String resultCode
```

Just do the following:

```
text1.setText(resultCode)
```

Comment: It cant , result from scanner not appear on edittext

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the result from scanner using intent or bundle (I can't figure out whether you are using an activity or fragment) to the next activity/fragment. Then use setText() to assign value to your editText.